# Could I use logloss as classifier performance measures when "Test & Score"?

Tags: orange

I try orange today, and want to use logloss as the classifier performance measures when "[Test & Score](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/evaluation/testandscore.html#classification)", but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I want do that in Orange GUI, and I only found AUC, CA, F1, Precision, and Recall in that.

Answer (score 1):

Hover on the scoring header and use right click. This should open a window where you can select logloss as well.

[image: screenshot]